ASP.NET Core Web API : entity doesn't get saved to database
I am creating a basic ASP.NET Core Web API which contains a list of countries/locations/places of interest.
I have created all the methods for location which are a child of the country object and everything is working as expected.
However I am trying to create a method for adding a point of interest (child of the location object) but it just doesn't save anything to the database, even though the code is laid out identically to how I am doing it for the location.
Here is my controller:
var finalPlaceOfInterest = mapper.Map<PlaceOfInterest>(placeOfInterestForCreation);

await repository.AddPlaceOfInterestAsync(locationId, finalPlaceOfInterest);
await repository.SaveChangesAsync();

Repository code
public async Task AddPlaceOfInterestAsync(int locationId, PlaceOfInterest placeOfInterest) 
{
    var location = await GetLocationAsync(locationId);

    if (location != null) 
    {
        location.PlacesOfInterest.Add(placeOfInterest);
    }
}

public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync() 
{
    return (await context.SaveChangesAsync() >= 0);
}

My PlaceOfInterest entity class is defined like this:
public class PlaceOfInterest 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location? Location { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
}

After calling repository.SaveChangesAsync, the finalPlaceOfInterest object should get populated with its ID and the Location & LocationID properties, but they are not being set and nothing is being persisted to the database.
I have identical code for creating a Location, but with the Country as its parent, and it works correctly and is saved. After calling the SaveChangesAsync method, the ID, Country & CountryID properties are populated.
What am I missing? Starting to go a bit mad here as I can't figure out why this won't work. I've added migrations and updated my database & all the tables & columns are correct.

This problem requires setting breakpoints to check which step of the data is abnormal. If there is no problem with the data, you can add try..catch... to the repository.SaveChangesAsync method, or find the SQL statement to be executed through EnableSensitiveDataLogging, and then manually execute it in the database for testing.

Does GetLocationAsync use .Include(x => x.PlacesOfInterest)?

Guys I solved it and of course it was me being stupid! On my Location entity I had the places of interest property declared like this:
public ICollection<PlaceOfInterest> PlacesOfInterest = new List<PlaceOfInterest>();
I forgot to include the {get; set;} for it. Thanks for the replies.
